# How to change value in 3d matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Assume that there is a matrix

```
m = magic(5)

ans =
    17    24     1     8    15
    23     5     7    14    16
     4     6    13    20    22
    10    12    19    21     3
    11    18    25     2     9
```

As known, in order to change a specific values (eg: change to `0` if greater than `10`) in a `m`×`n` matrix,

```
    m(m>10) = 0
m =
     0     0     1     8     0
     0     5     7     0     0
     4     6     0     0     0
    10     0     0     0     3
     0     0     0     2     9
```

I have a `k`×`m`×`n` matrix which consists of random `0`s, `1`s and `2`s. `k` has iteration values `1` to `10` and will not be changed.

How can I change `1`s to `0`s then `2`s to `1` sequentially? But `k`should be unchanged. Only the values in `m`'s and `n`'s.

Comment: There is no difference for 3D matrices. Do it exactly the same way.

Comment: I don't understand... if `k` is row, `m` is column, and `n` depth, any given element will have all three indices... Do you mean that for a given `k`, the `m x n` matrix should be changed?

Comment: I still don't understand... are you trying to not change the first column of the matrix for all the rows (or at least the first ten) and all of the depths? If that's the case, `temp = m(:,2:end,:); temp(temp==1) = 0; temp(temp==2) = 1; m(:,2:end,:) = temp;` should work, but there might be more efficient ways...

Comment: when you put `k` in for loop, you are essentially accessing the 2-D slices of a 3-D matrix (or in general, a n-1 dimensional slice of a n-D matrix). Instead of that, you can do it the same way as you do it for the 2-D case. For example, if `a` is a 3-D matrix, do: `a(a==1)=0 and a(a==2)=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example of "Do it exactly the same way":

```
>> m = round(rand(3,2,2)*2)
m(:,:,1) =
     1     1
     0     0
     1     2
m(:,:,2) =
     1     1
     0     1
     2     1

>> m(m==1)=0
m(:,:,1) =
     0     0
     0     0
     0     2
m(:,:,2) =
     0     0
     0     0
     2     0

>> m(m==2)=1
m(:,:,1) =
     0     0
     0     0
     0     1
m(:,:,2) =
     0     0
     0     0
     1     0
```

The 3D logical mask returned by `m==2` in this case can be used on any array with the same size.